# Is there way in C# to pass all agruments in callback function for the precalculate

Tags: c#, callback, functional-programming, arguments, lambda

I have such a method:

```
internal PointGeospatial ConvertToSpherical(double x, double y, double z)
```

I wonder, does exist such a possibility to handle all arguments in method in some functional style in C#, like (pseudo-code):

```
ConvertToSpherical(double x, double y, double z) ::(x) -> arg->Rad2Deg(x)
```

It's a pseudo code, but by the idea I think you get what I want. There is of course the way to make a sub-method, like `PrepareCoordinates(x, y, z)` where in `foreach` I would prepare 3 variables and send to the `ConvertToSpherical()`, but it's too imperative.

I wanna some cool lamda like (functional-language like) style. Is it possible in C# with my question?

Comment: @jyparask Why? It's actual about C#, I'm programming in C#, not C++.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand your pseudo-code: In real code, you can do `internal PointGeospatial ConvertToSpherical(double x, double y, double z) { x = Rad2Deg(x); y = Rad2Deg(y); z = Rad2Deg(z); /* rest of method */ }` Is that what you want to do in a simpler way?

Comment: -1 No research, you even knew the name for this syntax, albeit spelt wrong. A search for "C# lamda" yields results.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen you have do it 3 times, in functional language it would be made by :-> at once to any count of arguments

Comment: @weston there is research, yields aren't satisfied here... and it doesn't have anything similar with the functional languages possibility, so -1 to you for blind reading and misunderstanding

Comment: But am I right you want to project each parameter onto what `Rad2Deg` returns, and store the result in the same variable? I do understand you want a functional language like way of writing it, but I just need to be sure I know what the result should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you want to project each parameter onto a new value with the `Rad2Deg` method whose signature and return type is like a `Func<double, double>`.

I don't see any particularly nice way of doing it. The best is perharps:

```
internal PointGeospatial ConvertToSpherical(double x, double y, double z)
{
  var changedArgs = new[] { x, y, z, }.Select(Rad2Deg).ToArray();

  // rest of method
}
```

But it doesn't change the original variables, so you could still use `x`, `y` and `z` later, by accident.

If you changed the signature of the method to take an array (with `params`, so you could still call it with the same call syntax), you could do:

```
internal PointGeospatial ConvertToSpherical(params double[] x)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
    x[i] = Rad2Deg(x[i]);

  // rest of method
}
```

I can also do the last case with an arrow, but it is a little ugly. You need this:

```
namespace N
{
  delegate void ActionWithRef<T>(ref T obj);

  static class MyExtensions
  {
    public static void ForEachWithRef<T>(this T[] array, ActionWithRef<T> action)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
        action(ref array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
// ugly?
// included in this post because it looks a bit like the pseudocode of your question

internal PointGeospatial ConvertToSpherical(params double[] x)
{
  x.ForEachWithRef((ref double t) => t = Rad2Deg(t));

  // rest of method
}
```

Perhaps a bit less ugly to have:

```
namespace N
{
  static class MyExtensions
  {
    public static void MutateAll<T>(this T[] array, Func<T, T> selector)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
        array[i] = selector(array[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

and use with:

```
internal PointGeospatial ConvertToSpherical(params double[] x)
{
  x.MutateAll(Rad2Deg);

  // rest of method
}
```

I won't say I actually recommend any of these "solutions" when you have only three parameters, but it shows what you can do (and cannot do) in C#.

In all cases where I use `params`, if the caller of `ConvertToSpherical` chooses to call the method in unexpanded form, and if he keeps a reference to the `double[]` instance he passes, then he will find that the contents of his array have changed when the method returns.

Also with the `params` examples, of course it won't be checked at compile-time how many arguments (exactly three or not) are passed.

Here's the repetitive, non-functional solution:

```
internal PointGeospatial ConvertToSpherical(double x, double y, double z)
{
  x = Rad2Deg(x);
  y = Rad2Deg(y);
  z = Rad2Deg(z);

  // rest of method
}
```

;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for rush reading the Q. Here is one idea, use `IEnumerables` as vectors:

```
Func<IEnumerable<double>, IEnumerable<double>> convertToSpherical = a => a.Select(Rad2Deg);

var list = new[] {0, Math.PI, Math.PI*2};

var newList = convertToSpherical(list);

foreach (var i in newList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Where:

```
private static double Rad2Deg(double radians)
{
    return radians*180/Math.PI;
}
```

I find that having `x`,`y`,`z` variables is a pain and prone to copy-paste errors anyway, so would always recommend `array`s/`IEnumerable` vectors.